# IE8 and Modernizr: Object doesn't support this property or method?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modernizr

I'm using Modernizr 2.6.2 on a site in development and experiencing a frustrating error in IE8. I'm loading Modernizr in the head of the document:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.0-ck.js"></script>
```

Then I'm loading a base.js file at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. In that base.js file I have the following code ([Hastebin link for readability](http://www.hastebin.com/koyoturocu.php)):

```
/**
 *  Non-jQuery hasClass function for checking the existence of
 *  class names on elements.
 *  @param {string} scripts The string of scripts to check
 *  @param {string} cls The class name we're looking for
 *  @return {boolean} True or false
 */
/*
function hasClass(scripts, cls) {
    var r = new RegExp('\\b' + cls + '\\b');
    return r.test(scripts);
}*/


/**
 *  Get ID from <body> tag
 */
function matchBodyID(match) {
    return match.toLowerCase() === document.body.id.toLowerCase();
}


/**
 *  Check to see if the body tag has a "data-scripts" attribute.
 *  If true, collect the contents. If false, set to false.
 */
// var dataScripts = document.body.getAttribute("data-scripts") || false;


/**
 *  Variables must be defined before we can use them.
 */
var Modernizr = Modernizr || {},
    ScaleText = ScaleText || {};


/*
 *  Using Modernizr.load, we can run our tests to see
 *  which features are available to us and load our
 *  polyfills to handle those that aren't
 */
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
Modernizr.load([
    {
        load: [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js',
            'js/plugins/image-array-ck.js?t=' + timestamp,
            'js/plugins/jquery.debouncedresize-ck.js',
            'js/plugins/menu-ck.js?t=' + timestamp
        ],
        complete: function () {
            if (!window.jQuery) {
                Modernizr.load('js/vendor/jquery-1.8.1.min.js');
            }
            ScaleText.invoke();
            $("#skip-to-content").bind("click.menu", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this),
                $par = $($this.parent());
                $par.toggleClass("open");
            });
        }
    }, {
        test: matchBodyID('home') || matchBodyID('department'),
        yep: [
            'js/plugins/spin.min.js',
            'js/slideshow-ck.js',
            'css/royalslider/royalslider.css',
            'css/royalslider/rs-minimal-white.css',
            'js/plugins/tabs-ck.js?t=' + timestamp,
            'js/plugins/underscore-min.js'
        ]
    }, {
        test: matchBodyID('interior'),
        yep: [
            'js/plugins/spin.min.js',
            'js/plugins/tabs-ck.js?t=' + timestamp,
            // 'js/plugins/menu-ck.js?t=' + timestamp,
            'js/plugins/underscore-min.js'
        ]
    },
    // Check for iOS
    {
        test: Modernizr.appleios,
        yep: [
            'js/plugins/ios-ck.js'
        ]
    },
    // Functional polyfills
    {
        test: Modernizr.flexbox,
        nope: ['js/polyfills/flexie.js']
    }
]);




/*
 *  ScaleText
 *  An attempt to create a custom type scaler for
 *  large type that needs to scale to fit its parent
 */
ScaleText = {

    invoke: function () {
        $(".scalable").each(function (index, element) {
            var $parent = $(element),
                $wrapper = ScaleText.wrapIt($parent.first("div"));

            $parent.css({
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "opacity": 0
            });
            $wrapper.css({
                "-webkit-transform-origin": "left top",
                "-moz-transform-origin": "left top",
                "-ms-transform-origin": "left top",
                "-o-transform-origin": "left top",
                "transform-origin": "left top"
            });
            ScaleText.checkSize($parent, $wrapper);

            jQuery(window).on("debouncedresize.ScaleText", function () {
                ScaleText.checkSize($parent, $wrapper);
            });
        });
    },

    checkSize: function ($parent, $wrapper) {
        var scrollWidth = $parent[0].scrollWidth,
            width = $parent.width(),
            scrollHeight = $parent[0].scrollHeight,
            height = $parent.height(),
            ratio, wRatio, hRatio;

        wRatio = width / scrollWidth;
        hRatio = height / scrollHeight;
        ratio = (wRatio < hRatio) ? wRatio : hRatio;

        $wrapper.css({
            "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + ratio + ")",
            "-moz-transform": "scale(" + ratio + ")",
            "-ms-transform": "scale(" + ratio + ")",
            "-o-transform": "scale(" + ratio + ")",
            "transform": "scale(" + ratio + ")"
        });
        $parent.css({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    },

    wrapIt: function (element) {
        var content = $(element).html(),
            $wrapper = $("<div>" + content + "</div>");
        $(element).empty().append($wrapper);
        return $wrapper;
    }

};
```

For some reason IE8 is completely choking at the `Modernizr.load` block, saying only `Object doesn't support this property or method`. Screenshot attached.

Ideas around why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

I should mention I'm using a custom build of Modernizr: http://www.hastebin.com/fitaqireha.coffee

[image]

Comment: Did you work this one out? Have just tripped over the very same scenario and problem.

Comment: Having the same issue in IE9 though

Answer (score 1):

I got this too.  Looks like Modernizr.load() is optional.  The following is from the header of modernizr-2.5.3;

```
/*     
 * Modernizr has an optional (not included) conditional resource loader
 * called Modernizr.load(), based on Yepnope.js (yepnopejs.com).
 * To get a build that includes Modernizr.load(), as well as choosing
 * which tests to include, go to www.modernizr.com/download/
 */
```

You'll need to go to [here](http://www.modernizr.com/download/) and get the package again - be sure to check *Modernizr.load* under the *Extra* category.  Doing so will include yepnopejs at the end of the file.

[This](http://hastebin.com/yarahepite.coffee) is what is appended, i stuck it in my existing modernizr.*.js and all is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same "Object doesn't support this property or method" error, in IE8 (though not in Chrome).

Because I had other pages referencing the same Modernizr declaration script, I suspected my issue was elsewhere. It turned out I had an extra comma in the load block:

```
Modernizr.load([
   {
      load: [
         'path/to/something.js',,  // <--removing this extra comma resolved the issue
         'path/to/something-else.js'
      ]
   }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a .NET developer living in Visual Studio and I used the general ['Modernizr' NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Modernizr/) and stumbled onto this same issue: it does NOT include the `Modernizr.load()` (aka `YepNope`).

**I would like to tip .NETters to use an [alternative NuGet package 'Modernizr full'](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Modernizr.full/) that DOES include the `load()` function**.

Besides that the full version also also includes a minified .js version, while the general one doesn't (though I prefer generating minified versions myself with VS's [Web Essentials extension](http://vswebessentials.com/)).

Also note that the main NuGet package does seem more up to date (currently at Modernizr v. 2.8.3, e.g. the latest) while 'Modernizr full' is currently at 2.6.2). But for me that suffices. Ofcourse if you need all the shiny new and trimmed you should use the [Modernizr download](http://modernizr.com/download/) feature as the accepted answer states.